# Spring integration exception stacktrace like Apache camel?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is it possible to have something like Apache Camel stacktrace when an exception is thrown ?

[image]

Right now I have some issue for debugging my application because when an exception is throw, the only thing I have is the class name (so I can't debug the flow and I can't see his path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you mention in the screen shot has the same name in Spring Integration - [Message History](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history).

When message travel we store there in the headers (`MessageHistory.HEADER_NAME`) the path. And that is available in logs as well.

After message has traveled you can get access to that object in the message via `MessageHistory.read(message)`. This Object is a `List<MessageHistory.Entry>` extension, where each entry has this properties for access:

```
public static final String NAME_PROPERTY = "name";

public static final String TYPE_PROPERTY = "type";

public static final String TIMESTAMP_PROPERTY = "timestamp";
```

I agree that we might not have similar pretty-print for this `MessageHistory` object, but at least we have something for your consideration.

When exception is thrown in the Spring Integration it is an instance of `MessagingException`. Its `failedMessage` can be used to extract a mentioned history.

Feel free to open a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) with the improvement request.